# How to change the background color of a html page using forms and php?

Tags: php, html, forms

After inputting a color of choice the page should change its background color. It should be done using html forms.

```
<body bgcolor="<?php $_GET["color"]; ?>">
    <form method="get" name="color">
        Background color:<br>
        <input type="text" name="color">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS instead of HTML attributes to decorate your HTML rendering. Also you should [avoid to use inline styling](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm) which represents a better organization since it's separating languages (= separating your CSS from your HTML).

So to answer your question, you can do that :

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET["color"]) || $_GET["color"] === '')
    {
        $_GET["color"] = 'pink';
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Website</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: '<?= $_GET["color"] ?>';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" name="color">
            Background color:<br>
            <input type="text" name="color">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo the value stored in the variable `$_GET["color"]` like

```
<body bgcolor="<?php echo $_GET["color"]; ?>">
```

and you should also check if the variable `$_GET["color"]` exist and not null using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) like

```
<body bgcolor="<?php echo ( isset($_GET["color"]) && $_GET["color"] ) ? $_GET["color"] : "pink"; ?>">   // here pink is the default color
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if(!empty($_GET['color']) {?>
        <body style="background-color:'<?php echo $_GET['color'];?>">
    <?php }else {?>
        <body style="background-color:orange">
    <?php } ?>
    <form method="get" name="formcolor">
            Background color:<br>
            <input type="text" name="color">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```